# How to list all roles with Permissions,in spatie permission Package?

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-permission

I'm using spatie package for roles and permissions in my laravel project, I need to list all roles with their permissions in a table, is there is any way?

```
[  
   {  
      id:1,
      name:"role1",
      "permissions":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Permission 1"
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"Permission 2",
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: You can list all roles with Role:all() and you can list all permissions with Permission:all()
You can list all permissions assigned to a role with $permission->roles and all roles assigned to permissions with $role->permissions.

Comment: got it with this - $role_permissions = Role::with('permissions')->get(); thank you  @DhananjayKyada Kyada

Comment: Get all roles:
$roles = \Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::all();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it with this:

```
$role_permissions = Role::with('permissions')->get();
```

*(answered by questioner)*